# Relativistic reference frames - What is the independent variable?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, reference-frames, metric-tensor, geodesics

Currently reading the following document  - [Moyer (1971)](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19710017134.pdf). Excellent read if anyone is interested.

I note that in Eqs. $(12)-(20)$, Moyer uses the coordinate time as the affine parameter in the Euler - Lagrange equations of motion. I am terribly confused about this. Normally, for a timelike geodesic the affine parameter is the proper time. Later in the document the independent variable will be the geocentric coordinate time or the Barycentric coordinate time. Does anyone have a simple explanation why they don't use the proper time?

The notation is the same in the [IERS technical note](http://iers-conventions.obspm.fr/2010/2010_official/tn36.pdf) for Eq. $(10.12)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple: The goal in that technical report is to establish a relativistically-correct framework via which an N-body problem can be solved numerically, where N is smallish, but is larger than two. In particular, the goal is to describe the solar system.

General relativistic effects in the solar system are small, considerably smaller than are the perturbations that result from the Newtonian gravitational interactions amongst planets. This means it makes much more sense to use coordinate time rather than proper time. (This raises the question: Proper time of what? This is an N-body problem, after all.)

Comment: I don't know. I thought the job would be done using the proper time of some Probe or satellite that needed tracking. I'm not sure. I find this new time concept quite confusing still!

Comment: @Rumplestillskin - That's nice for a particle of negligible mass orbiting a single central body that is quite compact and rather massive. (Note: In a relativistic context, the Sun is far from compact, and is a bit of a lightweight.) The solar system has other objects of interest in addition to the Sun. Those other objects act on each other (and on the Sun), and also on probes we humans send beyond Earth orbit.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm getting it. Do you know of any references that discusses this? I'd like to read more at an introductory level.