# Help with equations of motion

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, relativity, geodesics

**Important note:**

---

The reference system is the Geocentric Celestial Reference System (GCRS) and the coordinate time $t$ is the independent variable. More details can be found in [my other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340423/relativistic-reference-frames-what-is-the-independent-variable).

I have no doubt the problem lies with my inability to identify something trivial but maybe some fresh eyes and some experience from the community can push me in the right direction.

---

**Question Background:**

---

I'm faced with the following Lagrangian

$$ L = \left[ \left( 1 - 2 \left(\frac{\mu}{r}\right) + 2 \left(\frac{\mu^2}{r^2}\right)  \right) - \left( 1 + 2 \left( \frac{\mu}{r} \right)  \right) (\mathbf{\dot{r}} \cdot \mathbf{\dot{r}}) \right]^{1/2}, $$

where $\mu = GM = \text{const.}$ and  $ r=|\mathbf{r}|.$

The above Lagrangian comes from the Eddington-Robertson-Schiff (or the first post-Newtonian approximation) line element in a Geocentric Celestial Reference System so the coordinate time $t$ is the independent variable.

I'm interested in determining the equations of motion associated with such a Lagrangian. The result will give the general relativistic correction for the acceleration of a near-Earth satellite/object.

**Problem and question**

---

The associated equations of motion are [given by](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19710017134.pdf) (Eq. 20)

$$\frac{d^2\mathbf{r}}{dt^2}  = \frac{\mu}{r^3} \left[ \left(4 \frac{\mu}{r}  - v^2 \right) \mathbf{r}  + 4 (\mathbf{r}\cdot \mathbf{\dot{r}} ) \mathbf{\dot{r}}\right]. $$

I cannot for the life of me obtain this using the Euler-Lagrange equations.

**Attempt at a solution:**

---

The Euler-Lagrange equations are given by

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{\dot{r}}} \right)  - \frac{\partial L}{ \partial \mathbf{r}} =0.$$

Bearing this in mind and working through the process using

$$ L = \left[ \left( 1 - 2 \left(\frac{\mu}{r}\right) + 2 \left(\frac{\mu^2}{r^2}\right)  \right) - \left( 1 + 2 \left( \frac{\mu}{r} \right)  \right) (\mathbf{\dot{r}} \cdot \mathbf{\dot{r}}) \right]^{1/2}, $$

I end up with nonsense to be frank.

Alternatively, using $L^2$ we can use a "modified" form of the Euler Lagrange equations [given by](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19710017134.pdf)

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left( L\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{r}}} \right) - \left( \frac{L\dot{L}}{L^2} \right) \left( L \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{r}} } \right) - \left( L \frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{r}} \right) =0,$$

where the terms used can be obtained by various derivatives of $L^2$.

However, I seem to be off by a factor of two and end up with extra terms!!

Does any one have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

The use of $\dot{X}$ in general relativity has confused you. Let $\lambda$ denote an affine parameter of the geodesic. Define $\dot{X}:=\frac{dX}{d\lambda}$ for any $X$ so $ds=\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu}=\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}^\nu}d\lambda$ and we may take the Lagrangian as $\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}^\nu}$. Note that $t$ is not an affine parameter, but $s$ is, and we may as well take $\lambda=s$.

It can be shown that squaring the choice of Lagrangian still gives the same equations of motion, and this removal of the surd makes life considerably simpler. In general the EOM is the *geodesic equation of motion*, $\ddot{x}^\mu=-\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\rho}\dot{x}^\nu\dot{x}^\rho$ (remember the derivatives are with respect to $s$ rather than $t$), and you can quote this general result. It should give you the equation of motion you want.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more specific! I know what you are saying and that is the formalism that I am also used to. However, I believe it to be different in the GCRS. I've given details above.

Comment: Also, I think you have made a typo in labelling the equation. That is the geodesic equation of motion not of deviation. I believe the geodesic deviation equations involves the Riemann tensor? It relates to coalescence or recession of objects in a varying gravitational field right? The above question is much simpler. However, very basic calculus is failing me and I can't see where!!!! Always the way until I see it I guess.